# htaccess remove file ext for folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried looking at other tutorials and examples but nothing quite fits my scenario. My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=view&id=$1&title=$2

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /%1/? [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

I'm using PHP and need to rewrite /index.php?page=page&moreparamaters=1

But I also have a folder on the server called /admin/ and I want to remove the .php extension from the files in this folder so that:

`/admin/lol.php` becomes `/admin/lol/`

I have lots of these files so I can't really add each one in, individually. How can I do this without affecting my index.php rewrites?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to think the other way round. Assuming that all your files are placed in the folder directly (meaning, no subfolders), this will work:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^\/]*)? /admin/$1.php [L,R]
```

In your links you may then write /admin/lol/ or /admin/lol, both will be redirected to /admin/lol.php